# Link css file codeigniter

Tags: css, codeigniter

I have the following codeigniter project file structure

```
test/
    application/
    assets/
        css/
           style.css
    system/
```

I been trying to link the css file to a page in views the following:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/css/style.css">
```

I have configured the base url

```
config['base_url'] = 'https://localhost/test/'
```

This doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: inspect element and see what is actual URL became.

Comment: url from element inspection is https://localhost/test/assets/css/style.css so that is correct.

Comment: Are you sure your localhost is `https://`? Try `config['base_url'] = '//localhost/test/'`